# Did not get cell value in update panel used Gridview

Tags: c#

My question is I have used an update panel on my page. There is a GridView, in this data bind on the time of a text box. My problem is if I click on the Select command field, I should get selected row cell values. But now I get only selected index no values from the specified cell on the selected row. I have get only row index from selected row. I need cell value from the further coding. If anyone know please share your knowledge. I remember you I have used update panel on my page. My need is getting selected row value. I don't care about which event is using..

My code is below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" style="margin-left:130px;" runat="server"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
     BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
     CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="MachID" 
     onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" 
     PageSize="2" onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
     onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
     onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
     <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Punch No">
      <ItemTemplate>
        Punch <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
          </ItemTemplate>
             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <%--  <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Punch"></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>--%>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="MachID" Visible="False" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="PunchTime" HeaderText="Punch Time" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblhidden" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Punchtime") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:CommandField SelectText="Edit" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                   <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" 
                             onclick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                     </Columns>
                      <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                       <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                       </asp:GridView>
           </td>
```

My Code here:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

        //e.NewSelectedIndex
        int i = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        string data = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;       
        if (data != "")
        {

            txtpunchin.Text = data.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first cell seems to be a template field. If so, you cannot get value with `Cells[0].Text;`

Answer (score 0):

check this....

```
buttonclick()// this must be ur edit button
{
    Button btn= (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    string name= grv.Cells[0].Text;

// once update your updated panel if it wont trigger any value, just like
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: I check on autos .did not see any value on the Rows..thats the reason. no vale on the name.name is null

Comment: ok u are working on gridSelectedIndexChanging, now it depends on which row u have selected, but its index change, not row selection, if u wont select any row, how can u get row cell value ?

Comment: I am used button event didi notget value..also I tried with select index  changing an changed event..In changind index will get but could take Row values with that selected iindex.